# how to make Responsive image for mobile sites

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website which must be responsive for mobile phones. I've created it using my desktop. When I adjust browser windows it's working perfectly for mobile phone but when I check it on my real mobile phone: Microsoft- 640 it's not responsive to the mobile view.[Website working fine in all devices except Windows phone]

Comment: Use bootstrap or foundation framework if you are not familiar with Responsive HTML (Media Query).

Answer (score 0):

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class.

Refer url: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be missing in adding the `meta viewport tag` in the `index.html`. The meta viewport is defined inside `<head>` tag like this :

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

For more information about meta viewport, you can read this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) from w3school. Hope it helps